# Architecture concern. Automated communication between secured web-services

Tags: rest, docker, web-services, security, architecture

Let's say we have a service A that automatically needs to contact service B over night. It's a new requirement, before they were supposed to work independently. Both services are secured, so it is impossible to reach one another without user being logged in (and pass JWT or cookie).

Now, apart of complaining how bad this architecture is, what is the best direction to achieve the communication? Add a technical user? Or maybe put everything behind a docker-compose? Anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service 2 service communication should always happen through pub-sub model. You can send messages from service A and service B will listen to those messages and perform the desired work. There will be no need for any new user creation